# how to change drop down list based on gridview selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a drop down list which will load up with a series of customer ID numbers. I then have a gridview control on my page with the select hyperlink. When i click on the link to select the row in gridview i would like my dropdown to change to that number.

Below is what i have tried but doesn't work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (!GridView1.SelectedIndex.Equals(-1))
    {
        DropDownList ddl;

        ddl = (DropDownList)form1.FindControl("ddl_Customers");
        ddl.SelectedValue = (String)GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Values[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you rephrase please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event for `GridView1`

```
void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ddl_Customers.SelectedValue = GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: The GridView select link looks like this: `javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Select$0')`

Comment: I get the error: `Data keys must be specified on GridView 'GridView1' before the selected data keys can be retrieved.  Use the DataKeyNames property to specify data keys.`

Comment: Did you try setting the `DataKeyName` property on the Grid? Like `DataKeyNames="CustomerID"`

Comment: Thanks for your advise. it changes the drop down.. but i have code against index changed in the ddl and thats not firing now.. I thought if the value in the dropdown changed then my code would fire?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString()` for this. To use that, you should define a `datakeyname` like this: `<asp:Gridview DataKeyNames="CustomerID">`

Then all you need is this:

```
void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ddl_Customers.SelectedValue = GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```